# MySQL "LIKE" clause for filtering against strings

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a filter system for my site. The current code looks like this:

```
$DB->query("SELECT id FROM filter WHERE filter LIKE '%". $Properties['Title'] ."%'");

if($DB->record_count() != 0) {
    $Err = '[b]Cannot upload this![/b]';
    include(SERVER_ROOT . '/sections/upload/upload.php');
    die();
}
```

*Note: $DB->record_count = function to cover mysqli_num_rows

Ofcause, we got $Properties to be the properties of uploaded element, and thereby Title to to be the string title

Example, an upload could be:
Me.And.My.Dog.At.The.Lake

and there is a record in the filter database saying:
me.and.my.dog

The objective of the code is to make an error and not allow the upload to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can do it with a query like this

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) matches
  FROM filter
 WHERE 'Me.And.My.Dog.At.The.Lake' LIKE CONCAT('%', filter, '%')
```

**Note:**

1. reverse upload name and `filter` when doing comparison with `LIKE`
2. return just the number of rows in the resultset using `COUNT()` instead of returning a resultset that potentially can contain multiple rows (even if it's only ids) and then read the count on the client side.
3. Consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of interpolating query strings.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92d28/3)** demo

Comment: "Consider" seems too lenient, prepared statements *must* be used.

Comment: A problem seems to occur, when i then put though something with the title of "Me.And.My.Cat.At.The.Couch", seems to be caught with the filter "Me.And.My.Dog"

Comment: @user2674081 Why it's a problem? You just need to make your mind you either use exact matching or a pattern matching with `LIKE`. What it should be?

Comment: The problem is that neither seems to work. I want it to math a pattern, but the pattern has to be found exactly as it is.

Answer (score 1):

use following statement  to fetch row count

```
         if($DB->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) != 0) {
          $Err = '[b]Cannot upload this![/b]';
              include(SERVER_ROOT . '/sections/upload/upload.php');
             die();
              }
```

Comment: as mentioned, $DB->record_count() is a cover function for mysqli_num_rows, and the $DB var is not et up in such a way to support fetch. $DB is a custom class, not the one created by mysqli opening of a db